# Caching Python requirements for production deployments

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm building various python-based projects that use pip/buildout to install dependencies. But I don't like the idea of someone deleting a github project and crippling my apps, or a network outage meaning I can't perform a deployment.

How do other people solve this?

I've got various ideas, but I think perhaps the one that sounds most promising would be some kind of caching proxy server. I'd point pip to use this internal proxy server which would cache a copy of the downloaded project, and periodically check for updates (if there's a net connection) before serving cached versions.

Does anything like this already exist?

**Use case:**

I have a project which I deploy to web server 1. I add new features with a remote dependency, and when I come to update to the production web server, PyPi is down so I can't deploy. Or perhaps when I come to set up a new web server, a dependency has disappeared from github or wherever.

How can I make it so my deployments/dev environments can always be brought up regardless of what happens in the wider world?

Also, when I deploy, I won't deploy over the top of existing code. Rather I'll build a new virtualenv and switch over to it so I can rollback if anything goes wrong. So each time I deploy I'll need to rebuild my environment and will need dependencies to exist.

So I'm looking for a solution that will insulate me against short-term network outages to servers hosting dependencies, as well as guarding against projects being deleted.

Comment: I'm actually working on something to handle this very thing. Development is slow at the moment as the need isn't extremely high. However, at the moment I've been hacking around pip to get this kind of functionality to work. At the moment I have it to where pip doesn't have to run any C compilations. Once I get an actual project going for this that has more than just proof of concept additions I'll let you know! It shouldn't be more than a few days that I'll have something rudimentary on github. If you want to wait for it my github is https://github.com/ravenac95. Cheers!

Comment: "Or perhaps when I come to set up a new web server, a dependency has disappeared from github or wherever"?  If it's gone, you need to revise your software, don't you?

Comment: @S.Lott no, i need to revise my deployment which is exactly the point of this question

Comment: @ravenac95 - that sounds good. I found 'collective eggproxy' (http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/annoucing-collectiveeggproxy-the-smart-pypi-mirror/). I'll keep an eye out on github for your project.

Comment: The author removed the project.  And you're going to continue using it in spite of it's being removed.  That strikes me as a remarkably bad engineering choice.  You won't upgrade or rewrite to reflect those changes?  You just keep plugging forward with a package so bad and outdated it was removed?

Comment: I think you're missing the point. I'm not talking about long-term engineering decisions. I'm talking about catering for a situation when a site is under load and I need to bring up additional nodes in a hurry. I need to cater for the possibility that pypi might be down, or projects might not be around any more.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a "reference copy" of the projects on which you depend.

If someone removes the project from GitHub (and PyPi and all the mirrors, and every other site on the net) then you have the source and can now distribute it.

Comment: yes, but i want an automated system that will do that that pip/buildout can hook into so I don't need to manually install these things myself.

Comment: What?  I install the dependencies once.  Folks who install will install things once and then do updates from time-to-time, when testing confirms that everything's good.  I'm not sure what you're trying to "automate".  Can you clarify by **updating** the question with an example or scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same requirements, and also use buildout to manage my deployments.  I try not to install ANY of my package dependencies system-wide; I let buildout install eggs for all of them into my buildout.  That way if I depend on a newer version of some package in rev N+1 of my project, and at "go-live" time N+1 falls on its face, I can roll back to N and automatically get the packge dependencies that N worked with.

We run a private eggbasket server, and configure buildout to fetch packages only from that. Server contents were initialized by allowing buildout to grab eggs from the network one time, then copying the downloaded eggs.

This way, upgrades to each package are totally under control and I can ensure that 2 successive buildouts of the same snapshot of my code will build out the same thing.  When I want to upgrade all, I will let buildout fetch most-recent-versions again, test test test, then copy my eggs to the eggbasket server to go into production mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm looking for:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.eggproxy